# UICollectionViewCell dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier gives a hidden cell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a UICollectionView and I'm using dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier to reuse cells. The second time cellForItemAtIndexPath is called, a hidden cell is returned - thus the cell does NOT show up in my UICollectionView. I try to hardcode the cell to not be hidden - but this does not work, and the hidden property stays at "YES" even after setting it to "NO". What is causing the cell to be hidden - and how can this be negated?

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SFReceiptCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setHidden:NO];

    NSLog(@"cell.hidden = %d", cell.hidden);
    ...
```

This is shown in the logs:

> cell.hidden = 1

No where is the code is the cell being hidden - so I don't know what may cause this to happen.

Comment: Did you set hidden for any other views?If not, you should check your reuse logic.

Comment: Same issue happening for me also did u fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same issue. I spent 3 hours in debugging and trying to set `.hidden = false` without success.
Turns out that adding:

```
override func applyLayoutAttributes(layoutAttributes:UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes)
{
    super.applyLayoutAttributes(layoutAttributes)
    self.updateSubviews()
}
```

In `UICollectionViewCell` subclass that I am using in project solved the problem.
Im using `updateSubviews()` to update frames since I do not want to use autolayout in cells.

Comment: Method where I am changing frames of cell's subviews.